# Which basic modules do you recommend to disable for performance and other? - Magento2

Tags: magento2, module, performance, magento2.4.2

Which basic modules do you recommend to disable for better performance or other reason?

(I solved a checkout issue after disabling Dotdigitalgroup_Sms module.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this To check module dependencies
bin/magento info:dependencies:show-modules-circular

It will generate csv file with dependency

Then you probably come to know which is required and which is not

Mostly get disable core module are

Magento_Marketplace

Magento_NewRelicReporting

Dotdigitalgroup_Email

Dotdigitalgroup_Chat

Vertex_Tax

Vertex_AddressValidation

Yotpo_Yotpo

There are few more

And also check this module Yireo_DisableLog2

If your System does not use GraphQl

Then here is the command

php bin/magento mod:dis Magento_CatalogCustomerGraphQl Magento_WishlistGraphQl Magento_GroupedProductGraphQl Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl Magento_WeeeGraphQl Magento_VaultGraphQl Magento_CatalogUrlRewriteGraphQl Magento_CatalogCmsGraphQl Magento_TaxGraphQl Magento_SwatchesGraphQl Magento_UrlRewriteGraphQl Magento_InventoryGraphQl Magento_SendFriendGraphQl Magento_SalesGraphQl Magento_RelatedProductGraphQl Magento_ConfigurableProductGraphQl Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl Magento_GroupedProductGraphQl Magento_BundleGraphQl Magento_QuoteGraphQl Magento_CmsGraphQl Magento_CheckoutAgreementsGraphQl Magento_CatalogRuleGraphQl Magento_StoreGraphQl Magento_CatalogGraphQl Magento_EavGraphQl Magento_AuthorizenetGraphQl Magento_BraintreeGraphQl Magento_DownloadableGraphQl Magento_CustomerDownloadableGraphQl Magento_PaypalGraphQl
Magento_CmsUrlRewriteGraphQl

Also check this link
Link: https://rocketweb.com/blog/decrease-magento-2-load-time-just-by-disabling-modules

Hope this might help you

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use multiple stocks and sources, you can disable the MSI modules https://meetanshi.com/blog/disable-magento-msi/